# Free online video cropper

Tags: gratis, web-apps, video, video-editing

Is there an online (no software to install) free tool that:

- allows to crop a video in space (i.e. modify the top left and bottom right corners)
- allows to crop a video in time (example: only keep from 0'20" to 0'35" and discard the rest)
- or both
- does not require uploading the video to a server on internet, but instead works locally in the browser (probably with some JS and/or WASM librairies that can edit MP4)

?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would name OpenShot as a multi-platform video-editing tool but it is an application rather than a web-app. But OpenShot does all the things except for the "browser"/JS part.